# Need Help on isPerishable():boolean

Tags: java

> If the GrocItem is perishable, toString() will include "Perishable".  If the GrocItem is not perishable, the toString() method will not include "Perishable".

Here is my code and I'm stuck on it:

```
public class GrocItem extends Item{

private boolean perishable;

public GrocItem(String name, double price, int qty,boolean perishable) {
    super(name, price, qty);
    this.perishable = perishable;
    perishable = false;
    
}

public boolean isPerishable() {
    return perishable;
    
}

public void setPerishable(boolean perishable) {
    this.perishable = perishable;
}

public String toString() {
    return getName() + "\t" + getPrice() + "\t" + getQty();
 }

}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? Do you know about `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use an if statement in your toString:

```
public String toString() {
    if(isPerishable()){
        return getName() + "\t" + getPrice() + "\t" + getQty() + "\t" + "Perishable";
    } else {
        return getName() + "\t" + getPrice() + "\t" + getQty();
    }
 }
```

Comment: this is correct. However you just did OP's homework for him/her without any of his/her own effort.